# Graphviz Dot file failing to compile in Windows Emacs

Tags: windows, emacs, graphviz, dot

I took the following steps to use Graphviz Dot mode in emacs:

- as per instructions at http://ppareit.github.io/graphviz-dot-mode/, added

  (load-file "PATH_TO_FILE/graphviz-dot-mode.el")

  to my .emacs file (C:/emacs/.emacs for me), and copied the text from    http://www.graphviz.org/Misc/graphviz-dot-mode.el to a file in that path.
- in Emacs, created a new file (c-x c-f) and named it something.dot.  Copied the DOT text from the aforementioned website, which became highlighted for dot syntax.
- Selected all text and pressed C-c c.  Was given the following message:

  dot -Tpng c:/emacs/dot_test.dot > c:/emacs/dot_test.png
  'dot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.

  Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu Jul 30 06:36:12

Comment: Have you [installed Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php)? The Emacs mode simply interfaces with the separately installed `dot` utility; it doesn't implement Graphviz itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first install graphviz to your system.  The Windows installer is found [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php).

I was able to use it successfully without making any changes to my PATH (which they say would be an issue), however be aware you may need to add it to your path.

Comment: I unpacked the zip file into C:\graphviz and added GRAPHVIZ_DOT to my environment variables with the path C:\graphviz\graphviz-2.38\release\bin\dot.exe.  Still displaying the same error message when I run in emacs.  I tried pip install graphviz, which said that graphviz was installed successfully, other than what I've already done I'm not sure what installing graphviz entails..

Comment: It shouldn't be part of `GRAPHVIZ_DOT`, it should be added to `PATH` so that it can be found as an executable.