# Graphviz's dot tool on Windows

Tags: java, windows, graphviz, dot

I've created a Java program to write a .dot file as I'm using the [Graphviz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) software to visualize some data.
There is nothing wrong with a code itself, but when I try to execute the following command in command prompt:

```
dot -Tpdf data.dot -o data.pdf
```

in a folder where my Java code is located, I get the following error:

> 'dot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

How can I fix this?

<sub>The only similar question I found related to this problem is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727211/graphviz-dot-file-failing-to-compile-in-windows-emacs). However, it doesn't seem quite clear to me how could it be helpful in this particular case.</sub>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to add the directory (folder) where you installed Graphviz to your `PATH` environment variable. How to do that depends on which version of Windows you have, but for a start, you can look at this [answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, executing the command "set path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin" in a folder where my code is located did the trick.

Comment: @Bouhraoua Hi, Where should I run command, and how, please could share how you solved issue, because I am having same issue

Answer (score 3):

These days you could use [Chocolatey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet#Chocolatey): `choco install graphviz`

That seems to add it to the path as part of the install.

Comment: choco works much better than pip. It worked right away contrary to pip!

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Graphviz is a folder (container) which contains the "dot" executable. Therefore your modified PATH should lead to **dot.py** and not just the container **Graphviz**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in my case I could not use any solution that required administrator privileges (e.g., changing environment variables).

So I downloaded the ZIP file [from Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/download/) and just changed the working directory to the install directory temporarily to call `dot` or spell out the path to the `dot` command.

E.g.:

```
dot -Tpdf data.dot -o data.pdf  &REM Doesn’t work
C:\pathTo\Graphviz\bin\dot -Tpdf data.dot -o data.pdf  &REM Works
```

Comment: Why is it `&REM`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm just using an in-line comment for the Window's command-line. Equivalent to Linux ```echo foo  # This line has an `echo` ```